# \node not recognized by Tex

Tags: tikz-pgf

I decided I'd learn how to do some graphics in latex, and I'm following this video at the moment:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LoBC8zIB-3k&feature=youtu.be

However, every time I try to run the code, it tells me that \node isn't recognized.This is what I've put in so far for testing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows,positioning}

\tikzstyle{startstop} = {rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=red!30}
\tikzstyle{io} = {trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110, minimum width = 3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=blue!30}
\tikzstyle{process} = {rectangle,minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=orange!30}
\tikzstyle{decision} = {diamond, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=green!30}
\tikzstyle{arrow} = {thick-->,>=stealth}
\begin{document}
                \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
                \node[startstop] (start) {Start};
                \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Welcome! You are using the wrong syntax, `\tikzstyle` expects square brackets after the `=` sign. This triggered the error. However, you should not use `\tikzstyle` anyway, you should switch to `\tikzset`. Here is a minimally modified version of your code that works.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows,positioning}

\tikzset{startstop/.style={rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm,
minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=red!30},
io/.style={trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110, minimum width = 3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=blue!30}
process/.style={rectangle,minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=orange!30}
decision/.style={diamond, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=green!30}
arrow/.style={thick-->,>=stealth}}
\begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
   \node[startstop] (start) {Start};
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you actually want to use the `arrow` style, you should use `arrow/.style={thick,->,>=stealth}`, but I would recommend not to call this style arrow, so maybe `marrow/.style={thick,-stealth}`.

Answer (score 0):

Your styles's options must be wrapped by brackets, not curly braces.

This is the syntax for `\tikzstyle`:

```
\tikzstyle{name} = [some options ...]
```